# Shifting primary keys of several rows at once

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I have a table titled `KEYS` that looks like the following. The `id` and `version` columns are both primary keys.

```
||  id* |  version* |  value  ||
--------------------------------
||  1   |     1     | "asdf"  ||
||  1   |     2     | "jkl;"  ||
||  1   |     3     | "qwerty"||
--------------------------------
```

I want to insert a row in between version 1 and 2 so that it will look like so:

```
||  id* |  version* |  value  ||
--------------------------------
||  1   |     1     | "asdf"  ||
||  1   |     2     | "zxcv"  ||  <--
||  1   |     3     | "jkl;"  ||
||  1   |     4     | "qwerty"||
--------------------------------
```

Notice that the `"jkl;"` and `"qwerty"` rows have had their `version` value incremented by 1. I have tried the following query to increment the version numbers by 1, however, the query errors because version `2` cannot be incremented since it will conflict with the version `3`:

```
UPDATE KEYS SET version=version+1 WHERE id = 1 AND version >= 2
```

Does anyone have a way that I can insert my new row while incrementing the other rows's versions?

Note: I am connecting to an MS Access database via an OleDB driver from a c++ application.

Comment: I assume by "The id and version columns are both primary keys." you really mean that your table has a composite key for those two columns?

Comment: And why are you changing the primary key? Do you have nothing that refers to this table via foreign key elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is yet another good reason to use anonymous primary keys, rather than composite primary keys.  But, that is your structure.

One way is to reassign `id` to a non-sensical value and then assign back:

```
UPDATE KEYS
    SET id = -1, version = version + 1
    WHERE id = 1 AND version >= 2;

UPDATE KEYS
    SET id = 1
    WHERE id = -1;
```

Two updates for the price of one!

Comment: I inherited this structure from someone else, and no changes to the structure are allowed unfortunately.

Also, do you mean "One update for the price of two!" ;)

Answer (score 1):

No you really are going to have to just use two separate statements:

```
UPDATE KEYS SET version = version + 1 WHERE id = 1 AND version >= 2
```

And then execute:

```
INSERT INTO KEYS (id, version, value) VALUES (1, 2, 'zxcv')
```

If you can change your database structure I would recommend using a single primary key field that has no value other than providing a relationship to other tables.  Composite keys can cause serious slow down in MS Access when working with large amounts of data.